# How do you globally set the default browser using KDE4?

Tags: configuration, default, browser

I'm using awesome-wm on Kubuntu 10.10. I like some of the KDE tools... like choqok. Thing is, that within awesome wm it seems to be impossible to set a default browser, because KDE4 settings overwrite the generally desired settings:

To illustrate the problem:

```
% xdg-mime query default text/html  
chromium-browser.desktop
```

And from `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`

```
[General]
BrowserApplication=firefox.desktop
```

Which does in no way make sense to me. If I set Firefox as default xdg-mime should not have Chrome. In fact I want Firefox.

So how do I globally once and for all, across all frameworks, define Firefox as default?

Best,
Marius

p.s.: I should probably mention, that clicking in Choqok starts Konqueror...

Comment: Look for default apps in system settings?

Comment: aehm... did you read this question at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I go to the start menu, then:

System Settings->Default Applications->Web Browser

and then I tell it to open http/https in: 
 
`google-chrome`

Now links in choqok (or any other kde application) are opened in chrome,
also, if I do `alt+f2` and type `"man:file"` for instance, the man page opens in chrome.

I also modified the default email client so that emails are launched using gmail using the following command:

`google-chrome "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to="%t`

Comment: Very handy!  default browser worked like a charm.  But that email line didn't work from gwenvew for sharing an image - the image itself wasn't loaded as an attachment.  Can that be made to work as well?

Answer (score 2):

I have here KDE 4.6 (Beta of course) but am sure this worked in 4.5.x because i was opening everything with Firefox.

Right click on a html file, choose properties and on the window that appears click on the small button next to the format of the file (html in this example). The button is small and to the right of the format. There you can choose which one will be the default one. The default one should be on top, the first one in the list will be the default for all html files.

I did this for avi, mpg, mp3, png, jpg, htm, php, js, css files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (Kubuntu 16.04):
go to  : `System Settings->Default Applications->Web Browser`
and put `chromium-browser`
[image]

Comment: now it is in System Settings->Personalization: Applications->Default Applications->Web Browser, or just type in a search form 'browser'

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to do 2 thing:

1. Change the web browser default applications in the system settings:

`System Settings->Default Applications->Web Browser`

2. Add default **HTTP** and **HTTPS** handler in `mimeapps.list`:

Using whatever editor you prefer, you might need `sudo` for that, add the `x-scheme-handler/http` and `x-scheme-handler/https`:

`vim ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

You should end up with something like this:

```
[Default Applications]
...
...
...
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
```