# Reset default Browser to Firefox after install Chrome in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, default-browser

I'm developing a webInterface so I installed Opera and Chrome on my **KUbuntu 16.04.** System (additionally to Firefox which I usually use)

BUT ... It seems that **after installing Chrome** some services use Chrome es default browser though Firefox **IS** my default browser!

e.g. If I click on a URL in Thunderbird -> opens in Chrome
If I click directly on phpmyadmin from the KStarter -> opens in Chrome

Before installing Chrome everything just opened in Firefox

Any idea how to make Firefox **REALLY** default browser again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could fix it by the

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

mentioned in other threads before.

Only I had to remove Chrome and Firefox before because update-alternative got an error (it said something like "there are no browser installed".. I'm sorry I didn't copy that)

So now I've chosen Firefox again as system-default and until now it does what it's supposed to do.

(anyway it's strange that the Default Settings of the System itself didn't work at all)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Settings manager to update the default Web Browser. Take a look on this thread: [How to golbally set default web browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19855/how-do-you-globally-set-the-default-browser-using-kde4), at the end, an user solved this, by chosing the desired web browser on `Default Applications -> Web Browser`.

To make Mozilla Firefox the default, just type firefox in the input text field.

Comment: Hi, first off all thanks! I did that, and after reboot it still says "firefox" but unfortunatly mentioned apps still open in google-chrome :/

In the moment I'm doing a reinstall of firefox and chrome and try again update-alternatives --config x-www-browser (which before failed for some reason)

Comment: Hi, please, leave a comment with the results of this to keep us updated. I hope that work for you, so, many people could solve similar problems with your procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it finally worked:
1.  uninstalled (purged) both browsers;
2. installed firefox and made it system-default
3. checked it back with the update-alternatives
4. installed google-chrome
5. tested it with thunderbird and phpmyadmin
-> no it works as it's supposed to

Comment: Excellent!, have a nice and funny Ubuntu experience. Hehehe. Best regards.